# PATCH https request from Parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, parse-platform

I'm trying to make an https PATCH request from Parse Cloud code (to update part of an object in a Firebase application), and I'm running into the following issues:

- Parse.Cloud.httpRequest doesn't support PATCH, and does a GET request instead, so I'm trying to use Node.js https module to do the request, but:
- The https module isn't included in Parse Cloud Code and I'm not sure how to include it

Anyone having tried something similar with Parse?

For now my fallback is to do a PUT request instead an update the whole object, but if anyone has some experience with these issues that'd be great

EDIT: Someone from Parse just replied [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/http-patch-request-with-parsecloudhttprequest#answer-we-dont-support-this-yet-but-we-will-add-it) saying that they don't support PATCH requests as of now but will do in the future

Answer (score 4):

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method : 'POST',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'PATCH',
        },
        url : 'https://dev-xxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/users/91'+userNumber+'.json',
        body : {
            "code" : code
        },
```

Try this, followed by a success and error block. It works for me! You need to set method type as `POST` and this extra line in headers:

```
'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'PATCH',
```

Comment: Glad I was able to help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's unfortunately no way to send `PATCH` request using Parse Cloud now. Only way is to check if your provider offers a fallback for clients not supporting `PATCH`. Some services listens to `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header (as prateek31 mentioned) or using their own mechanism (for example `?_HttpMethod=PATCH` GET parameter for Salesforce.com).