# PATCH Requests from Parse Cloud Code

Tags: rest, http, parse-platform, server

I fiddled for hours trying to implement outgoing PATCH requests from Parse Cloud Code before learning that it does not support them.

Out of technical curiosity, why would such a service support POST, GET, PUT, etc. but not others, such as PATCH? Are there security concerns? Is it just additional code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PATCH https request from Parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997645/patch-https-request-from-parse)